# Number of classes of K-sets

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, algorithms, coordinate-systems

I am having a plane in N dimension.
Th distance between 2 points (a1,a2,...,aN) and (b1,b2,...,bN) is max{|a1-b1|, |a2-b2|, ..., |aN-bN|}.

I need to to know how many K-sets exist(here K-set refers to set of points whose distance between  2 points of set is K).But as there can be infinite number of these K-sets. Thus, we would only like to count the number of classes of K-sets, such that any two K-sets which belong to the same class are equivalent if they follow given conditions.Two K-sets X and Y are considered equivalent (and belong to the same class) if:

```
They contain the same number of points 
There exists N integer numbers (t1, ..., tN) such that by translating each point of X  
 by the amount ti in dimension i (1≤i≤N) we obtain the set of points Y.
```

Let's consider N=2, K=4 and the following sets of points X={(1,2), (5,5), (4,3)} and Y={(2,5), (5,6), (6,8)}. Let's consider now the tuple (1,3). By translating each point of X by the amounts specified by this tuple we obtain the set {(2,5), (6,8), (5,6)}, which is exactly the set Y. Thus, the two sets X and Y are equivalent and belong to the same class.

Example let say N=2 and K=1 .

There are 9 classes of K-sets. One K-set from each class is given below:

```
{(0,0), (0,1)}
{(0,0), (1,0)}
{(0,0), (1,1)}
{(0,1), (1,0)}
{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)}
{(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)}
{(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)}
{(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
```

So answer here will be 9.

Comment: You want your points to lie on the integer lattice?
Otherwise, there are infinitely many classes (you can rotate the set)

Comment: also, the distance between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is not one.
so it is not $1$-set...
Can you be more precise in the definition of $K$-set?

Comment: @user68061 It is one as we can see max{|0-1|,|1-0|}=1 .And k-set is one in which the maximum distance in that set of points is k

Comment: oh, yes, sorry I misunderstood )

Comment: @user68061 Their can be infinte K-sets i agree. But they will be equal under the mentioned conditions and hence will lie in same classes.So i want to count number of these classes not the count of sets